# ASP.NET Form tag client id or name in c#

Tags: asp.net

How can I get the name or id of the form which asp.net rendered on client side from c# at server side.

Or is it "aspnetForm" always ?

Comment: I'm curious why you would need it? In WebForms, there is (traditionally) only ever one form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form could be accessed via the [`Page.Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.form.aspx) property. So to get the form client id just use:

```
var formId = Page.Form.ClientID;
```

to get the name attribute use:

```
var formName = Page.Form.Name;
```